# Чем отличаются концепция ссылок и указателей в C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Не понимаю в чём концептуальное отличие ссылки от указателя в C#.
Пример ссылки - `var a = new Random()` - переменная а содержит адрес объекта в куче, этот адрес должен же хранится в каком-то виде? В каком? Это просто абстракция над указателями? Объясните пожалуйста, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ссылка указывает на управляемый CLR объект, указатель - это просто адрес в памяти, число. Внутри ссылки закопан указатель, верно, но он может без вашего ведома быть изменен сборщиком мусора на другой при перемещении объекта с места на место, а вы даже этого не заметите.

Comment: В с# ушли от использования ссылок и указателей в том виде в котором это в си для того что бы пользователи не делали ошибок. с# или использует явно обьекты в памяти, это структуры и переменные типа int double и т п, всё остальное это указатели, но используется точка везде.

Comment: @nick_n_a в C# ссылка на объект - это ссылка, а неуправляемый указатель на адрес памяти это указатель. Не путайте автора. В C# можно писать код, похожий на C с использованием указателей, он называется `unsafe` - небезопасный. То есть в C# есть и ссылки, и указатели.

Comment: С unsafe хуже работать. IIS unsafе не ест. 99% либ написано без использования unsafe. Вместо указателей можно использовать IntPtr и маршалинг, но это сложнее.

Comment: **var** - это как макрос. Cлужебное слово `var` заменяет тот тип который нужен переменной. Т.е. `var a = new Random()` эквивалент `Random a = new Random()`, а `var x = 1` эквивалент `int x = 1`, это упрощает написание кода в разы. `var ` всегда соответствует конкретному типу который вычисляется выражением справа.

Comment: @nick_n_a ничего сложного ни в маршаллинге, ни в работе с указателями нет, дело навыка, тем более уже придумали прекрасные спаны, где можно мучать стек как хранилку не прибегая к небезопасному коду. А потом "хуже", это чем что или чем где?

Comment: кроме того,  в C# есть аналог указателей в виде переменных, объявляемых с ключевым словом ref